# How to print Indian Currency symbol in pdf?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-generation, regioninfo

I can show the symbol in a messagebox, but it will not display in a PdfPCell.  I want to use the currency symbol in a billing system.

```
RegionInfo myRg = new RegionInfo("IN");

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell n1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Net Total " + myRg.CurrencySymbol + ": 200));

table.AddCell(n);
```

Comment: i can show the symbol in messegebox but it will not display in pdfpcell.. Please help. i want to use the currency symbol in billing system. It will Print Dollar or Pound Symbol  but not INR Symbol

Comment: You need a font with the currency glyph, helvetica (the default font) doesn't have it. Arial should work.